# How to declare weak delegate (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates, weak-references

I'm about to use **weak delegates** for some event listening. Mainly for not to worry about unsubscribe all the time.

If I'm right, using strong referenced (default) delegate does not let the subscriber object to be released from memory, this is I want to avoid.

But I'm not quiet sure how to declare weak delegates using UnityEngine, and .Net 2.0 Subset in Unity 3D. Should I use [`WeakReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) class somehow?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C I understand its an off-site resource, but its a good read by one of the developers of Sharp Develop

Comment: Thanks, seems helpful!

Comment: You don't usually have to worry about unsubscribing. Only in very specific situations.

Comment: It left unreferenced / leaking objects all over the place. And they are still do their job, but they should not, they should go away, but events don't let them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody needing to use a ConditionalWeakTable or WeakReference in .NET 3.5 for Unity there is a backport of it here: https://github.com/theraot/Theraot/wiki/Features